# Code structure for multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to scrape multiple URLs using python threading.  I think the structure of my code is incorrect because it takes almost the same amount of time running without threading as with threading.  The file "List.txt" containes URLs.  I appreciate any help.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'}
q = Queue()

print_lock = threading.Lock()


def threader():
    while True:
        with print_lock:
            properties = q.get()
        create_doneFile(properties)
        q.task_done()


def create_doneFile(properties):

    p=0
    for eachp in properties:
        try:
            p = (p+1)
            url = (properties[p-1])
            print(str(p)+ ' - '+str(url))
            html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            jsinfo = soup.find_all("script")

            list_of_interest = ['hl.config.value1', 'hl.config.value2']

            d = {}
            for line in jsinfo[9].text.split('\n'):
                if any(word in line for word in list_of_interest):
                    k,v = line.strip().replace('hl.config.','').split(' = ')
                    d[k] = v.strip(';')
            l1 = (d['value1']).replace('"','')
            l2 = (d['value2']).replace('"','')
            tblData = {'URL':url,
                       'value1':l1,
                       'value':l2}
            df = pd.DataFrame(tblData, index=[p])
            with open("ReturnData.csv","a") as csf:
                df.to_csv(csf, header = False)

        except Exception as e:
            continue
            print('there was an error' +str(e))

    print("Complete")
    print('Entire Job Took: ',time.time()-start)

with open("List.txt",'r+') as f:
    properties = f.read().splitlines()
    q.put(properties)

start = time.time()   


for x in range (10):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()


q.join()
```

Comment: In `threader` function there's no need to use a lock to access the queue object. `Queue` is thread-safe, so access is synchronized which makes using locks superfluous with this object.

Comment: I appreciate your help!  Is there anything else in the code that is keeping it from running faster with the threader function?

Comment: You probably want to synchronize access to the output file. Otherwise you're likely to either get interleaved output, or there is some mutual exclusion locking going on. Any number of things might be going on. For example, you're running 10 threads, but if you only have four processor cores, you're not going to get as much of a boost. And if all of your urls are on the same host, the host could be throttling you, or the runtime might be preventing you from sending multiple simultaneous requests to the same host.